# MySQL SUM function

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the sum of a column.

My Schema is as below...

[image: scheme screen shot]

I'd like to get the SUM of 'bill'.

I have the following...

```
   <?php
   $uid = $_SESSION['oauth_id'];
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users`, `income`, `outgoings` WHERE users.oauth_uid = '$uid' and income.user_id = '$uid' and outgoings.user_id = '$uid'") or die(mysql_error());
   $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
   ?>

   Outgoings = <?php echo $result["SUM(total)"];
```

I'm not receiving any output, however. Can anybody see where I'm going wrong? There's definitely data in my table.

Comment: because `$result` has no index `SUM(total)`

Comment: What Jack said. Write your SQL in the SQL query.

Comment: Why are you bringing the world to you? do you use everything you get? else you could only do `SELECT sum(bill) FROM users`.

Comment: Im using everything yes, im new to PHP, is this bad practice?

Comment: No, AFAIK this is not a bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SUM` function must be used when deciding what to return from the select.  Like so.

```
   SELECT SUM(`bill`) FROM `users`, `income`, `outgoings` WHERE users.oauth_uid = '$uid' and income.user_id = '$uid' and outgoings.user_id = '$uid'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you don't want to do a SUM() query as already proposed by others:

```
<?php
$sum = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $sum += $row['bill'];
}
?>
Outgoings = <?php echo $sum; ?>
```

But remember that you will need this if you want to reuse the same $query resultset:

```
<?php
     mysql_data_seek($query , 0);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just query for the `SUM` directly? Like:

```
   <?php
       $uid = $_SESSION['oauth_id'];
       $sum = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(`bill`) FROM `users` WHERE users.oauth_uid = '$uid'") or die(mysql_error());
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will get you the sum:

```
SELECT sum(bill) FROM `the_table`
```